# Return index of dictionary values, when dict values are a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary structured like this:

```
 key: [value1, value2, value3, value4, value5]
```

I'd like to access value2 & value 3, but db.values() returns all the keys in my dict, and db.values()[0] returns the first key. Is there a way to access all the "value2s" and "values3" for each key in my dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use slicing within a list comprehension to do this.

```
[value[1:3] for value in d.values()]
```

Example

```
>>> d = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,4,6,8,10], 'c': [1,1,1,1,1]}
>>> [value[1:3] for value in d.values()]
[[1, 1], [4, 6], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: You can use `values()` rather than `items()` if you don't need the keys for anything.

Comment: Now that would make more sense, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: I would use `itervalues()`. I bet this will be faster. :)

Comment: @wenzul - `dict.itervalues` would be the fastest, but only on Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x, `dict.values` is already lazy.

Comment: This worked brilliantly, the cleanliness of python never ceases to amaze me.

Comment: @wenzul - I can't reproduce that behavior in the interpreter.  Running `timeit('[value[1:3] for key, value in d.iteritems()]', 'from __main__ import d')` on my system returns `2.7241613110045364` while running `timeit('[value[1:3] for value in d.itervalues()]', 'from __main__ import d')` returns `2.4815463976565297`.

Comment: @iCodez Damn sorry, you are right. I used `-m timeit` in the wrong way :(